# How to fetch info from Osclass to Android App

Tags: php, android, json

So Osclass is a Open Sour Classified Ads.
I want to know how is possible to fetch information from my website to an Android App. For example I want to make the user of my app to register on my website while using the app and not having the need to go on my website and register from there. So let's say for example someone registered on my website through a web browser and then he downloaded my App, he will be able to sign in through the app because my website is connected to the app.

And I would like to fetch for example the categories and the listing of the categories on my website. I tried to search on google since Osclass is written in PHP, HTML and CSS so I thought it would be the same fetching information from a Wordpress website to Android app but I was really confused.

Should be there an API or JSON from Osclass themselves so I am able to create an App like I described or I can do it by myself creating JSON or whatever that I need to do.

An example would be Gumtree.com (Classified ads website) and their app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gumtree.android

Is there a tutorial showing how to fetch information from websites such as the login details and the ability to register?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no proper API for Osclass. However, there's some work in progress on that from the community (see [here](http://forums.osclass.org/development/a-rest-api-server-for-osclass/)).

For now, as we have the same need for our AngularJS search, we have made something like this :

```
function mdh_api_search() {
    $params = Params::getParamsAsArray();
    unset($params["sFeed"]);

    $params["location"] = str_replace(",","-",$params["location"]);
    $params["location"] = str_replace(" ","",$params["location"]);
    $data["url"] = osc_search_url($params);
    $data["title"] = meta_title();
    $data["results"] = getContent(getPath("search-results.php"));

    header('Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

    echo (json_encode( $data));
}
osc_add_hook("feed_api", "mdh_api_search");
```

This uses the feed_api hook (feed feature from Osclass) to get the items for a bunch of search parameters.